# Installation of ubuntu as only OS on ASUS X402CA

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, uefi, asus

I just got an ASUS X402CA; it has UEFI and secure boot. The system specs are in here:
http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X402CA/#specifications

I'm planning to run Ubuntu as my main and only operating system. As this is only a desktop, I have always setup partitions this way:

- 20 GB on /
- 8  GB on swap - for suspend and hibernate
- the rest goes on /home

I have read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI -- it says that I don't have to worry if I run Ubuntu in UEFI or if I'm running Ubuntu as the only OS.

What version of Ubuntu do you recommend for this?
Do I need to add any partitions?
Do I have to disable secure boot, fast startup, or anything else? or is it just as simple as installing Ubuntu?

I don't care about having Windows, but I do care about having a system up and functional.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install Ubuntu recently as Dual-Boot with preinstalled Win8.1 UEFI. What Microsoft did there is one hell on earth, so this didnt work.If you really want Ubuntu only there should be no problem: just deactivate the options safe boot and fast boot. to disable fast boot you have to go to win8 options, the other option is in the thing that once was the bios. If you have a raid, turn it off until installation finished,once the installation was successful you can turn it on again.